# In Manhunter, was Dr. Lecktor a cannibal?

Tags: book-adaptation, manhunter

In *Manhunter*, Brian Cox plays Dr. Hannibal Lecter (spelled Lecktor in the film)  – Lecter's first on screen portrayal. Hannibal Lecter is famously a cannibalistic serial killer, but I cannot recall if *Manhunter* dropped the cannibal part of his character or not. I recall a scene in which Will Graham tells his son Lecktor killed college girls, but I don't remember any other details. This [screenplay](https://sfy.ru/?script=manhunter) mentions the word "cannibal" once in the description of a headline referring to Lecktor:

> The caption reads: "Federal Manhunter Will Graham Recover-
>   ing from Near-Fatal Slashing By Hannibal 'the Cannibal'
>   Lecktor."

But as this is a screenplay, and not a transcript of the film, it doesn't confirm whether the element was dropped in the final cut.

Does anyone have a definitive answer? Was Brian Cox's Hannibal Lecktor a cannibal? Bonus question: I recall him being referred to as "Dr. Lecktor", but was his first name ever mentioned in the film?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## There is no specific reference to "cannibal" in *Manhunter*...

...that I can find in either the subtitles dialogue or on screen newspaper headlines.

Indeed, in the **original novel** the reference is only used in newspaper headlines. The FBI and Will Graham do not use this term nor can I find any reference in the novel to Lecter eating victims. This seems to have been a development for *The Silence of the Lambs*.

As for a reference to Dr Lecter/Lektor's first name there is only one as far as I can tell.

When the message from the Tooth Fairy is located they are told it was found...

> "In Hannibal Lecktor's cell. It was hidden in a book."

Comment: Fascinating addition about his history in the novels. It seems the phrase "Hannibal the Cannibal" does appear three times in the book, but it's interesting how downplayed this aspect is